# PvRecorder not reading fast enough on my Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, voice-recognition, voice

I'm using picovoice (rhino speech-to-intent and pvrecorder) on my pi0.
Here's my code:

```
from pvrecorder import PvRecorder
import pvrhino

#my pico voice key
key='my_access_key' #removed the access key

#rhino instance
rhino = pvrhino.create(
    access_key=key,
    context_path='/home/aashvikt/Desktop/MiniMate/Contexts/Mini-Mate-Commands_en_raspberry-pi_v2_1_0.rhn'
)

#created a recorder
recorder = PvRecorder(device_index=-1,frame_length=512)
recorder.start()

def getNextAudioFrame():
    return recorder.read()

while True:
    audioFrame = getNextAudioFrame()
    isFinalized = rhino.process(audioFrame)
    if isFinalized:
        inference = rhino.get_inference()
        if inference.is_understood:
            recorder.stop()
            intent = inference.intent
            slots = inference.slots
            print(f"intent: {intent}\nslots: {slots}")
            recorder.start()
        else:
            print('unrecognized')

rhino.delete()
```

Whenever I run this code, I get an error like
`[WARN]- Overflow: Reader not reading fast enough`

I'm using a usb microphone. What could the problem be?

Comment: The problem is that the processor in your very low end computer is not powerful enough to do voice recognition.  That's an algorithm that requires CPU power.